# How to mute & un-mute a player button?

Tags: javascript, mute

I am trying to build a buttun that suppose to mute and un-mute my player. 
For some reason I can only mute but can't un-mute the player.
The same function works fine with Play/Pause button...
Anyone has any iade?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <input type='button'  onclick="muteUnMute()"  value='Mute' class="btn_random" id="muteunmute"/>
 <audio controls="controls" preload autoplay="autoplay" id="audio1" volume="1.0"></audio>       

<script type="text/javascript">
  function muteUnMute() {
        var muteSound = document.getElementById("audio1");
        x = new Boolean(muteSound.muted=false);

        if (x) {
          document.getElementById('audio1').muted = true;
          document.getElementById("muteunmute").value="Un-Mute";
       } else {
          document.getElementById('audio1').volume="1.0";
          document.getElementById("muteunmute").value="Mute";
       }
    }

</script>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean `x = new Boolean(muteSound.muted == false);`, or better yet, `x = ! muteSound.muted;`

Comment: use `x = !muteSound.muted;`  as Paul Roub had stated

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce your function to just:

```
function muteUnMute() {
    document.getElementById('audio1').muted = !document.getElementById('audio1').muted;
    document.getElementById("muteunmute").value = (document.getElementById("muteunmute").value == "Mute") ? "Un-Mute" : "Mute";
}
```